# String called from CSV Ajax Call not evaluating with pure string

Tags: jquery, ajax, string, object, csv

I have the following call from a local CSV called via Ajax, when a dropdown list value is changed.

The CSV is then split into an array on each comma. Then we loop through and grab the correct value.

However, this line refuses to evaluate to true. I have set breakpoints and found that weFoundYou does equal "XXBO2" and options2[find2].toString() does equal "XXBO2" but the if statement will not evaluate.

```
if (weFoundYou === options2[find2].toString())
```

Full code:

```
$('#myoptions').change(function() { 

                    csvData2 = $.ajax(
                    {
                                    type: "GET",
                                    url: "data/stats5.csv",
                                    dataType: "text",
                                    success: function (result2) 
                        {
                            var options2 = result2.split(","); 
                            var selecthidden2 = document.getElementById('myoptions2');
                            var select2 = document.getElementById('myoptions'); 


                            var selectedText = select2.options[select2.selectedIndex].text;

                            var q = 0; 
                            var find = 0; 
                            var find2 = 180;

                            while (find < options.length) 
                            {
                                if (options[find] == selectedText) 
                                {
                                    var weFoundYou = "XX" + options[find - 1];
                                    find++;  
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    find++; 
                                }
                            } 

                            while (find2 < options2.length) 
                            {   
                                if (weFoundYou === options2[find2].toString()) 
                                {
                                    selecthidden2.options[find2] = new Option(options2[find2+1], find2);
                                    find2++;  
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    find2++; 
                                }
                            }



                        }
                            });
```

The annoying thing is that the FIRST if statement evaluates just fine!

```
if (options[find] == selectedText)
```

Contents of CSV file example:

```
XXB01, Somedropdownvalue, XXB02, Somedropdownvalue2
```

Contents of array:

```
XXB01, Somedropdownvalue, XXB02, Somedropdownvalue2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do all of the commas in the CSV file have a space after them? If so, try `split(', ')` (with the space after comma). It may be trying to match a string containing a space in `weFoundYou`. Also try `weFoundYou.toString()`, just in case.

Also, find2 starts on 180, so it skips a lot of the array before starting to search. The variable `q` appears to not be doing anything. Also, to clean up your loops, since you increment regardless of whether you find a match or not, try this:

```
while (find < options.length) {
    if (options[find] == selectedText) {
        var weFoundYou = "XX" + options[find - 1];
    }
    find++; 
}
while (find2 < options2.length) {
    if (weFoundYou === options2[find2].toString()) {
        selecthidden2.options[find2] = new Option(options2[find2+1], find2);
    }
    find2++; 
}
```

}

Comment: Also, what is `options` defined as? It is not defined in the function, but seems to be critical to understanding it.